# Does the server have to restart if opcache is enabled in php.ini?

Tags: php

I have just found it in cPanel, where I can set options and `php.ini` file. I have enabled **opcache** option. I am not seeing any  effect.

It's a shared server, so I can't restart it. Does the server have to be restarted for it to have an effect?

Comment: My guess is that it probably doesn't.  Is there some way that you could test if it is working and answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there are two functions that provide information on opcache.

- opcache_get_configuration()
- opcache_get_status()

Using the latter, I can see the stats change as I navigate the website.  So the server does **not** require a restart.

A sample dump

```
Array
(
    [opcache_enabled] => 1
    [cache_full] => 
    [restart_pending] => 
    [restart_in_progress] => 
    [memory_usage] => Array
        (
            [used_memory] => 9212208
            [free_memory] => 125005520
            [wasted_memory] => 0
            [current_wasted_percentage] => 0
        )

    [interned_strings_usage] => Array
        (
            [buffer_size] => 6291008
            [used_memory] => 317160
            [free_memory] => 5973848
            [number_of_strings] => 6738
        )

    [opcache_statistics] => Array
        (
            [num_cached_scripts] => 6
            [num_cached_keys] => 6
            [max_cached_keys] => 16229
            [hits] => 0
            [start_time] => 1662732928
            [last_restart_time] => 0
            [oom_restarts] => 0
            [hash_restarts] => 0
            [manual_restarts] => 0
            [misses] => 6
            [blacklist_misses] => 0
            [blacklist_miss_ratio] => 0
            [opcache_hit_rate] => 0
        )

    [scripts] => Array
        (
            [/home/example/public_html/lib/head.php] => Array
                (
                    [full_path] => /home/pacifi85/public_html/lib/head.php
                    [hits] => 0
                    [memory_consumption] => 3016
                    [last_used] => Sat Sep 10 00:15:29 2022
                    [last_used_timestamp] => 1662732929
                    [timestamp] => 1662506122
                )

            [/home/pacifi85/public_html/lib/common.php] => Array
                (
                    [full_path] => /home/example/public_html/lib/common.php
                    [hits] => 0
                    [memory_consumption] => 29248
                    [last_used] => Sat Sep 10 00:15:29 2022
                    [last_used_timestamp] => 1662732929
                    [timestamp] => 1662589081
                )

            [/home/example/public_html/downloads.php] => Array
                (
                    [full_path] => /home/example/public_html/downloads.php
                    [hits] => 0
                    [memory_consumption] => 3552
                    [last_used] => Sat Sep 10 00:15:29 2022
                    [last_used_timestamp] => 1662732929
                    [timestamp] => 1660393579
                )

            [/home/example/public_html/admin/info.php] => Array
                (
                    [full_path] => /home/example/public_html/admin/info.php
                    [hits] => 0
                    [memory_consumption] => 1264
                    [last_used] => Sat Sep 10 00:15:33 2022
                    [last_used_timestamp] => 1662732933
                    [timestamp] => 1662732831
                )

            [/home/example/public_html/lib/header.php] => Array
                (
                    [full_path] => /home/example/public_html/lib/header.php
                    [hits] => 0
                    [memory_consumption] => 4536
                    [last_used] => Sat Sep 10 00:15:29 2022
                    [last_used_timestamp] => 1662732929
                    [timestamp] => 1662587896
                )

            [/home/example/public_html/lib/footer.php] => Array
                (
                    [full_path] => /home/example/public_html/lib/footer.php
                    [hits] => 0
                    [memory_consumption] => 2504
                    [last_used] => Sat Sep 10 00:15:29 2022
                    [last_used_timestamp] => 1662732929
                    [timestamp] => 1662593866
                )

        )

)
```